# JavaScript run iMacros not running well, what's wrong?

Tags: javascript, csv, imacros

Here my js simple file. Please help what's wrong with this script?
if input value **10** or **more then 9** then will not run; done not run javascript. If below 9 then javascript run.

And the second problem, with this **for** looping style; (i change line 1 until line 4 and apply 173 lines script JS iMacros and read .csv file); why only read line 8 from .csv ?
**for 173 lines JS iMacros i was try run and perfect, no problems to read .csv and all done.** But after combining to use **for** looping, that's all above the problem. Please help.

```
var macro; 
macro =  "CODE:";
macro +=  "VERSION BUILD=8970419 RECORDER=FX" + "\n";
macro +=  "PROMPT \"Halo\"" + "\n";

var start_line = prompt ("Start row from", "5")
var end_line = prompt ("End of row number", "5")

for (var i=start_line; i<=end_line; i++) {
    iimPlay(macro);
}
```

Comment: You should use parseInt as the prompt returns a string

Comment: hi @juvian what and what it meant?
I do not understand the previous JavaScript. Can you give a practical not only on theory.

Comment: var start_line = parseInt(prompt ("Start row from", "5")) and same with end_line

Comment: i was put like your advise, but still read .csv line/ row number 8 but i only leave it 5 for starting and 5 for end of row.

Comment: Then the problem is with the macro, I don´t use iimPlay so don´t know

Comment: @juvian so what your suggest if not use iimPlay? btw as I have explained above macro iim as already become .js file is running well oke and already tested all perfect and done.    

But why if using "for" looping become not work?

Comment: for loop works: https://jsfiddle.net/92q8uosu/

Comment: oo i really don't understand and become more confused to see it. This is javascript + iMacros... i'm not familiar programming actually.. i only a little knowing iMacros and not understand much javascript.